# Is there an echo server I can use to test my programs?

Tags: echoserver

I'm writing a simple client to ping a server with a packet on port 7 (echo) and then waiting for a reply.  Is there a server that I can use to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple echo server:

```
sudo socat PIPE TCP-LISTEN:7,fork
```

Comment: sudo: socat: command not found

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo nc -vvlp 7 -e /bin/cat
```

---

If you happen to have a `inetd` installed, most of them have `echo` built-in. Snippet from `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
echo   stream  tcp nowait  nobody  internal
echo    dgram   udp wait    nobody  internal
```

Comment: (with nc.traditional / the one by Hobbit)

Comment: Tobu: Works fine on GNU netcat too.

Comment: Use `nc` from package `ncat` which supports option `-e` (as opposed to `netcat-openbsd`)

Comment: It doesn't work.  See bug https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/962